# TYPO3 - Use TS in Flexform OR flexform in flexform

Tags: typo3

I would like to run this flexform code with data from a table and the PID in SQL query set dynamically.

Is that possible?

```
<label>Selectbox from DB</label>
<config>
  <type>select</type>
  <items type="array">
    <numIndex index="0" type="array">
      <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
      <numIndex index="1"></numIndex>
    </numIndex>
  </items>
  <foreign_table>tt_content</foreign_table>
  <foreign_table_where>
     AND tt_content.pid = 22   <<<< no good at all.... What to do?
  </foreign_table_where>
</config>
```

Any of these would work fine if just the FF can access the PID:

- PID set as storage folder for plugin
- PID set in TS
- PID set in another flexform field (with reload) and then used in the query

BR. Anders

Answer (score 0):

"Semi" answer is that the storage folder set for the page that the pluin has been inserted into. The page storage folder can be accessed directly using marker ###STORAGE_PID###

use this line in example above:

```
  <foreign_table_where>
     AND tt_content.pid = ###STORAGE_PID###
  </foreign_table_where>
```

But I still would like to know how to reuse a value from the flexform like this or from TS set in the static extension template:

```
  <foreign_table_where>
     AND tt_content.pid = FIELD:previousFieldInThisFlexformAvailableAfterReload
  </foreign_table_where>
```